# Do not show users in welcome screen

Tags: release-freya

How do I add users without showing them in the welcome screen? I would like to add a user for ftp access but I don't need the person to show up in my elementary OS welcome screen. Same goes for my wife's account actually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your user as usual in User Settings.

To hide a user named `ftp`, modify or create a file named

```
 /var/lib/AccountsService/users/ftp
```

containing this:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. But now the "power/settings/lock icon" in my top right corner is gone.